# Elm JSON decoder for Union type with data

Tags: json, functional-programming, decode, elm

My json looks like this:

```
{"name": "providerWithVal", "value": "example"}
```

or like this:

```
{"name": "provider2"}
```

or

```
{"name": "provider3"}
```

My Elm union type is defined like so:

```
type Provider
    = ProviderWithVal String
    | Provider2
    | Provider3
```

I can write a decoder for a union type without data attached. But `ProviderWithVal` takes a string and I'm not sure how to make it all work.

This is what I have so far:

```
import Json.Decode as D

providerDecoder : D.Decoder Provider
providerDecoder =
    D.field "name" D.string |> D.andThen providerNameDecoder

providerNameDecoder : String -> D.Decoder Provider
providerNameDecoder string =
    case string of
        "providerWithVal" -> D.succeed ProviderWithVal
        "provider2" -> D.succeed Provider2
        "provider3" -> D.succeed Provider3
        _ -> D.fail <| "Invalid provider: " ++ string
```

Comment: The compiler complains about the first branch of my case statement. I feel like I'm close but I'm unsure how to get the value assigned to the `ProviderWithVal` constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick solution to your question is to replace `D.succeed ProviderWithVal` with `D.map ProviderWithVal (D.field "value" Decode.string)`

But I would create a helper to match the target strings, and then use that in the following way:

```
decoder =
    Decode.oneOf [ decodeWithVal, decodeP2, decodeP3 ]


decodeWithVal =
    exactMatch (Decode.field "name" Decode.string)
        "providerWithVal"
        (Decode.map ProviderWithVal <| Decode.field "value" Decode.string)


decodeP2 =
    exactMatch (Decode.field "name" Decode.string) "provider2" (Decode.succeed Provider2)


decodeP3 =
    exactMatch (Decode.field "name" Decode.string) "provider3" (Decode.succeed Provider3)


exactMatch : Decoder String -> String -> Decoder a -> Decoder a
exactMatch matchDecoder match dec =
    matchDecoder
        |> Decode.andThen
            (\str ->
                if str == match then
                    dec

                else
                    Decode.fail <| "[exactMatch] tgt: " ++ match ++ " /= " ++ str
            )
```